# Uncaught Exception: Could not find aws-sdk-core-2.6.49 in any of the source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile, gemfile.lock, camaleon

I am setting up a rails application with Camaleon CMS and i have been at it for 10 hours. The gemfile has been giving me so many problems. I can not start-up the server because of dependency issues.

```html
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta3/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 45133 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 44139 -- /home/daniel/Data/RubyOnRails/YoutubeBlog/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1.beta3, debase 0.2.2.beta9, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:45133
Uncaught exception: Could not find aws-sdk-core-2.6.49 in any of the sources
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `specs'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 /home/daniel/Data/RubyOnRails/YoutubeBlog/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/daniel/Data/RubyOnRails/YoutubeBlog/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
 /home/daniel/Data/RubyOnRails/YoutubeBlog/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'rake', '12.0.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'  # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.

#Basic Gems
gem 'hirb'
gem 'awesome_print'
# Additional Gems
gem 'devise-bootstrapped', github: 'king601/devise-bootstrapped'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rename'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog-google'
gem 'ads-rails'
gem 'camaleon_cms'
gem 'aws-sdk'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug' #rails debugger
  gem 'sqlite3' #using sqlite for development
  gem 'rspec-rails' # testing framework
  gem 'meta_request' # this gem allows integration with Chrome extension (not sure how useful this will be)
  gem 'better_errors' #displays a better error page
  gem 'binding_of_caller' # better_errors dependency
  gem 'quiet_assets' # this gem removes the asset pipeline related output generated in the rails web server console
  gem 'faker' # for generating test data
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end


#################### Camaleon CMS include all gems for plugins and themes #################### 
require './lib/plugin_routes' 
instance_eval(PluginRoutes.draw_gems)
```

I tried adding `gem 'aws-sdk'` to my gemfile but that didn't help. How do I fix this problem?.

Comment: 1. Check version of rails using this gem.
2. Check and update your rails version.
3. Reinstall this gem. ( try it if you still stuck)

Comment: I uninstalled rails 5, leaving 4.2.5. I now get `Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (12.0.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (12.0.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.` 
I specified `gem 'rake', '12.0.0'` in the gemfile but that doesn't fix it

Comment: Try this: 
    gem install rubygems-bundler  
    gem regenerate_binstubs

Comment: In my case for Ruby and fastlane, all I had to do was to ```bundle update```